# How to decompose the bias-variance-noise?

Tags: machine-learning, noise, bias-variance-tradeoff

Suppose I have a dataset, and I want to do a bias-variance-noise decomposition of a particular learning algorithm? What is the practical approach to do this? I think I understand how to calculate bias and variance. Do a k-fold cross-validation. Then the mean of the k error values could be the bias, and the variance is the variance of the k errors. But what about the noise? How I can I calculate the noise when the underlying function is unknown? Is there a a good estimation process?

Comment: Typically the decomposition is just something that I understand from a theoretical point of view. Understanding it helps me think through what I'm doing.